# Make an Actor repeat itself for a racing theme

Tags: ios, actor, gamesalad

I'm new to GameSalad. I have a background that is plain black an actor called "Road_Line". I want this actor to repeat itself on the screen to give the feeling of driving on  a road.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 3 simple steps.

1: Create a project with 2 actors- Road_BG(background) and Road_Line(stripes in your road).

Dimensions:

```
    Road_BG   = 320 x 480 (or screen size of your choise)
    Road_Line =  10 x 80  (I am using here. You can choose your own if needed)
```

[image]

2: In your `Road_BG` actor, create a timer with a Spawn actor behavior (as in figure below).

[image]

3: In your `Road_Line` actor, create a `Move To` behavior as below.

[image]

Hope this may help you to build your project...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @krs answer would be to set the actors up initially off the screen, put a behaviour on them to move downwards, then add a rule something like

- If attribute *this.position.y* < -40

  - Change attribute *this.position.y* to 520

(assuming the line actor is 80px high, so this would detect when the centre of the actor is off the bottom of the screen and then place it just off the top of the screen - also assuming that the screen is 480px high)

The advantages to this method are that it saves on the memory required to continually spawn actors at the top of the screen and then remove them at the bottom.